# How to build reports for an ecommerce webapp without slowing it down

Tags: java, mysql, optimization, aws, query

We have a medium sized ecommerce website which is entirely custom built in using Java and MySQL database on AWS infrastructure. Over a period of past several years, our orders volume has grown substantially high and so the size of our database.

From past couple of months we are facing a problem of slow CRM (Admin application) especially reporting. These reports are primarily built around customers and our orders data. Few points to be noted about our system

- We have two web apps - storefront & backend CRM application
- Storefront is mostly cached so impact is not much visible there
- CRM and storefront are connected to a single database server having a single schema
- We have added several indexes in our customer, order and order_item tables to increase speed of queries used in reporting.
- These three tables are mostly frequently used for reporting purposes. Also website keep adding new records in these tables when a new user registers or places order.
- AWS RDS used as database server runs at average 35% CPU
- If I run these queries directly on RDS using MySql workbench then also it is slow.

I want to understand, how could I possibly improve performance of our CRM application. What is the key area where do I need to work on which will have substantial impact.

- Is it infrastructure? Better database server?
- Optimization in queries needed?
- Better indexing in tables needed?

**Edit** - Added sample query

For example, I am running following query on **orders** table to fetch orders count for a specific date. It takes around average 3 second of time to return data. I expect queries like this shouldn't take more than 1 second of time.

```
SELECT count(*) as Count FROM orders WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ(CreatedDate,'+00:00','+05:30')) = '2018-07-30' 
AND OrderStatusId IN (5,10,15) AND Deleted = 0
```

There are several such queries, which gets fired to build a report. Which eventually presents any report to user not less than 10-20 seconds

**Edit** - Added modified queries and their response time

As per the answers, I have tested this query without `convert_tz` function and one without `convert_tz` as well as `date`. But results are not quite good. There is a gain of just 300 ms if I remove both `convert_tz` and `date` functions.I tested it multiple times, and everytime this is the difference between these queries.

1. Query 1 - time taken = **4.91 sec**

`SELECT count(*) as Count FROM orders WHERE date(CreatedDate) = '2018-07-30' 
AND OrderStatusId IN (5,10,15) AND Deleted = 0;`

2. Query 2 - time taken = **1.72 sec**

`SELECT count(*) as Count FROM orders WHERE CreatedDate >= '2018-07-30 00:00:00' AND CreatedDate <= '2018-07-30 23:59:59' AND OrderStatusId IN (5,10,15) AND Deleted = 0;`

3. Query 3 - time taken = **2.02 sec**

`SELECT count(*) as Count FROM orders WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ(CreatedDate,'+00:00','+05:30')) = '2018-07-30' AND OrderStatusId IN (5,10,15) AND Deleted = 0;`

Comment: Your last point seems to be key _If I run these queries directly on RDS using MySql workbench then also it is slow._. That said showing the table structure and queries might help us give you some pointers.

Comment: How slow is slow? How long does it take to get your query results, 1 sec, 10 sec, 1 minute, more? Are your queries returning lots of excess data? For example, all orders even if you only need those of last month or you need just the number of records?

Comment: Edited my question and added sample query, please check

Comment: for your sample query, store the date in utc and lose the timezone conversion

Comment: I have edited my question. Added tests of different queries without timezone conversion

Comment: it does seem slow but you don't provide enough info for us to optimise the query for you

Comment: Is it not possible to do the data filtering and conversion in Java? Java 8 has some very nice concurrent utilities and parallel streams with filters that will easily trump MySql in performance.

Comment: Also, if doing this in Java is not possible have you considered creating views for the queries that are required to build the report. These will be easily queried, as they will be another abstraction of the query, and they can be indexed as per your needs.

Comment: How many records are in your `orders` table?  Do all of them still need to be there?

Comment: @nikhiljhaveri I haven't been doing this in Java because I felt like I need to fetch more records and then filter from them which is unnecessary if I could fetch only the required data. And I haven't tried because in this particular case, I do not believe that I can gain much. But still I will give it a try. thanks

Comment: @DanPichelman Around 400,000 records I have. Pardon me, I do not understand your second question.

Comment: 400,000 records is very small.  You might want to verify which indices are being used.  As for my 2nd question above, I was assuming you had 10 million orders and perhaps your query would benefit from moving the old records to another table.

Answer (score 2):

Since you noted that your queries run slow when using the MySql Workbench, that's the first place to start.

In Sql Server, it's possible to view the query plan for a query and see exactly how the database will process it.  Furthermore, you can check to see which index (if any) is used.

In the case of your sample query, your `WHERE` clause contains a calculation `CONVERT_TZ(CreatedDate...)`.  Sql Server would see this and resort to a table scan - it would read every record in the table, do this conversion, then filter accordingly.  That's incredibly slow if you have a lot of records.

If possible, add a new field to that table `CreatedDateUTC` and do the calculation once.  You'll be able to create an index on that field afterwards.

In other words, start with your last two bullets

> Optimization in queries needed?
>   Better indexing in tables needed?

Comment: Also worth noting: In Postgres, you can actually create and index on the result of a function. Might be worth looking into for MySql.

Comment: I have edited my question. I tested variations of this queries to understand impact of `CONVERT_TZ` but results does not seems to be very optimistic. All my timestamps are already stored in UTC, I need to fetch them according to local timezone

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer to the problem of reports, which by their nature are slow to calculate is to run them against a data warehouse server rather than the transactional database.

This requires that you export your data out of your transactional DB. Normally this can be done as a continuous process.

A data warehouse database is structured differently to allow for fast report style queries and, as its a different server, queries against it wont affect the performance of your application.

However! your sample SQL seems pretty simple. It is probably slow due to the conversion of each rows date to a particular timezone. This is easily solved by the standard practice of storing dates as UTC.

It could be that some simple optimisation of your queries will enable you to run your reports against your transactional DB, or a simple replication of your Database to a failover/reporting server

Comment: Having a read replica optimized for reporting is a good idea, but I do feel like that we have reached to that scale. I have tested for timezone conversion function impact, edited my question please check